# Bootstrap collapse text/pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with the navbar and such, and I'd like to know how I can make the pull-right function work as I want to (I want my navbar links to be towards the right side of the screen instead of being right beside the navbar-brand).

I have also bumped into a problem with the collapse bar, mostly being the pull-right functions fault, it pulls the entire collapsed bar to the right so that you can only see the text and a small bar, making it almost impossible for mobile users to press a link because of the small size. 
Is there anyway to move the navbar text to the right without messing up the navbar-collapse?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navMain">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: if it worked for you then accept the answer so that other people can use it to.@james

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding pull-right on div with class collapse, add pull-right class to ul

Example

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I did try this, but it caused the same effect for me I found a fix for it and it was to put navbar-right on the ul class and that made it work, but thanks anyways!